# Why is the way of returning a view working on XAMPP and not on Ubuntu?

Tags: laravel

I created a local project using Laravel 5 on a XAMPP server. Returning the views from the controller is done by:

```
return view('base\frontend\\' . config('folder') . '\\pages.page', [
        'content' => $array
]);
```

On the XAMPP server it works fine, but on Ubuntu I need to change it into:

```
return view('base.frontend.' . config('folder') . '.pages.page', [
        'content' => $array
]);
```

Why is that? Is there a setting that needs to be changed? Cause I thought the first method was to go around it.

Comment: xammp isn't something you run "on". it's just a collection of software that runs on linu(x), of which ubuntu is a version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XAMPP system is on Windows, then I believe your error is occurring because Unix systems uses forward slashes as its directory separator while Windows uses backslashes, although I believe Windows works with forward slashes too.

The "standard" way of grabbing views within sub-directories (or the method suggested in the docs) is to use the dot notation.

> Of course, views may also be nested within sub-directories of the resources/views directory. "Dot" notation may be used to reference nested views.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/master/views

Comment: Thanx for this clarification. I will adapt this throughout this whole big chunck of coding ;)